# Approaching anonymous elements of array in JSON using Typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I have a problem with JSON array using TypeScript. I need to approach single anonymous elements and my code doesnt work. Here's declaration of my JSON code:

```
JSONobj: JSON;
this.JSONobj = 
[
{"Atributte1": "value1", "Atributte2": "value2", "Atributte3": "value3"},
{"Atributte1": "value4", "Atributte2": "value5", "Atributte3": "value6"}, 
{"Atributte1": "value7", "Atributte2": "value8", "Atributte3": "value9"} 
];
```

I want to access "rows". Here's my code that should write into console first row:

```
console.log(this.JSONobj[0]);
```

But all it returns is first character of JSONobj which is "[". So how should I modify my code to get to my console following code:

```
{"Atributte1": "value1", "Atributte2": "value2", "Atributte3": "value3"}
```

Thanks for every idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should work fine. I believe the error is elsewhere, You probably need to do a JSON.parse:

```
var JSONobj = 
[
    {"Atributte1": "value1", "Atributte2": "value2"},
    {"Atributte1": "value4", "Atributte2": "value5"}, 
    {"Atributte1": "value7", "Atributte2": "value8"} 
];

console.log(JSONobj[0]); // prints {"Atributte1": "value1", "Atributte2": "value2"}

var stringed = JSON.stringify(JSONobj);
console.log(stringed[0]); // prints '['

var parsed = JSON.parse(stringed); 
console.log(parsed[0]); // prints {"Atributte1": "value1", "Atributte2": "value2"}
```

[Try it](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=var%20JSONobj%20=%20%0D%0A%5B%0D%0A%09%7B%22Atributte1%22%3a%20%22value1%22,%20%22Atributte2%22%3a%20%22value2%22%7D,%0D%0A%09%7B%22Atributte1%22%3a%20%22value4%22,%20%22Atributte2%22%3a%20%22value5%22%7D,%20%0D%0A%09%7B%22Atributte1%22%3a%20%22value7%22,%20%22Atributte2%22%3a%20%22value8%22%7D%20%0D%0A%5D;%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log%28JSONobj%5B0%5D%29;%20//%20prints%20%7B%22Atributte1%22%3a%20%22value1%22,%20%22Atributte2%22%3a%20%22value2%22%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20stringed%20=%20JSON.stringify%28JSONobj%29;%0D%0Aconsole.log%28stringed%5B0%5D%29;%20//%20prints%20%27%5B%27%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20parsed%20=%20JSON.parse%28stringed%29;%20%0D%0Aconsole.log%28parsed%5B0%5D%29;%20//%20prints%20%7B%22Atributte1%22%3a%20%22value1%22,%20%22Atributte2%22%3a%20%22value2%22%7D)

PS: `JSONobj: JSON;` is incorrect (`JSON` is a special variable in modern browsers). Let TypeScript infer the type for you. But for 'accepts anything' objects use `any`

Comment: Yes I can see now, I did a mistake in my JSON object declaration. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: I wish I had of found this 3 hours ago :-). Thanks